# If pointers in C# do not inherit from object, are there still only objects?

Tags: c#, object, types, reference

I have read few discussions, saying that because everything in .NET inherits from the object class, everything (including primitive types) is an object. But as far as I know pointers do not inherit from an object class and there is no conversion to it.
Also in this context,not everything in C# is an object?

Answer (score 6):

From Eric Lippert's blog post [Not everything derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx):

> The way to correct this myth is to simply replace "derives from" with
>   "is convertible to", and to ignore pointer types: **every non-pointer
>   type in C# is *convertible* to object.**

Answer (score 0):

According to the definitions used in the C# Language Specification, only instances of reference types are objects. So neither value type values nor pointers are objects.

Therefore it is not true that "everything is an object" in C#.